# JADE (Java Agent Development Framework): cannot find agent on Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, agents-jade

I'm new to JADE. I'm trying to run an Agent on intellij, i already added the jade.jar file to the modules and checked the export option on the module and created a run configuration with the following characteristics:

- Main Class: jade.Boot
- Program Arguments: -gui -agents agent1:newPackage.NewAgent

Regarding the rest i've left it as it is.
I also created the NewAgent in the newPackage package and made it extend jade.core.Agent. With all that said, when I run the program it never works, always giving the following error:

```
dez 27, 2017 3:43:19 DA TARDE jade.core.Runtime beginContainer
INFO: ----------------------------------
    This is JADE 4.5.0 - revision 6825 of 23-05-2017 10:06:04
    downloaded in Open Source, under LGPL restrictions,
    at http://jade.tilab.com/
----------------------------------------
dez 27, 2017 3:43:19 DA TARDE jade.imtp.leap.LEAPIMTPManager initialize
INFO: Listening for intra-platform commands on address:
- jicp://192.168.1.3:1099

dez 27, 2017 3:43:19 DA TARDE jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.management.AgentManagement initialized
dez 27, 2017 3:43:19 DA TARDE jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.messaging.Messaging initialized
dez 27, 2017 3:43:19 DA TARDE jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.resource.ResourceManagement initialized
dez 27, 2017 3:43:19 DA TARDE jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.mobility.AgentMobility initialized
dez 27, 2017 3:43:19 DA TARDE jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.event.Notification initialized
dez 27, 2017 3:43:19 DA TARDE jade.mtp.http.HTTPServer <init>
INFO: HTTP-MTP Using XML parser com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser
dez 27, 2017 3:43:19 DA TARDE jade.core.messaging.MessagingService boot
INFO: MTP addresses:
http://mbp-de-stefan.home:7778/acc
dez 27, 2017 3:43:19 DA TARDE jade.core.AgentContainerImpl startBootstrapAgents
SEVERE: Cannot create agent agent1: Class newPackage.NewAgent for agent ( agent-identifier :name agent1@192.168.1.3:1099/JADE ) not found - Caused by:  newPackage.NewAgent
dez 27, 2017 3:43:19 DA TARDE jade.core.AgentContainerImpl joinPlatform
INFO: --------------------------------------
Agent container Main-Container@192.168.1.3 is ready.
--------------------------------------------
```

I think this happens only when I create a project and I run it on Intellij. If I create the same project on Eclipse and I run the project on Eclipse everything runs alright. Why does this happen?

Comment: Did you specify "use classpath for modude" in runConfiguration?

Comment: Yes I did the module is my project module, its the only option that appears